# DataSource.Error: Microsoft SQL: A conversão de um tipo de dados nvarchar em um tipo de dados datetime resultou em um valor fora do intervalo

Tags: powerbi

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JrpW.png)(Issue with data conversion for nvarchar type).

DataSource.Error: Microsoft SQL: A conversão de um tipo de dados nvarchar em um tipo de dados datetime resultou em um valor fora do intervalo.
Details:
DataSourceKind=SQL
DataSourcePath=rabbotdb-production.cld5znexge33.sa-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com;rabbotDB
Message=A conversão de um tipo de dados nvarchar em um tipo de dados datetime resultou em um valor fora do intervalo.
Number=242
Class=16

I've tried to use this code "SET DATEFORMAT ymd;" that I got in a previous query, which another guy had the same problem, although it didnt work.
Because even if it is possible to work, I don't know excatly where to insert it in my code.

SET DATEFORMAT ymd;

```
let
    Fonte = Sql.Database("serverx", "xx"),
    dbo_vw_PS = Fonte{[Schema="dbo",Item="dbo_vw_PS"]}[Data],
    #"Linhas Filtradas" = Table.SelectRows(ddbo_vw_PS, each [DataMovimentacao] > #datetime(2019, 6, 1, 0, 0, 0)),
    #"Linhas Classificadas" = Table.Sort(#"Linhas Filtradas",{{"DataMovimentacao", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Tipo Alterado" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Linhas Classificadas",{{"Valor Total do Serviço (REV.)", Currency.Type}, {"Valor Total das Peças (REV.)", Currency.Type}}),
    #"Coluna Duplicada" = Table.DuplicateColumn(#"Tipo Alterado", "DataMovimentacao", "DataMovimentacao - Copiar"),
    #"Tipo Alterado1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Coluna Duplicada",{{"DataMovimentacao - Copiar", type date}}),
    #"Consultas Mescladas" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Tipo Alterado1", {"IdCarro"}, Carro, {"Id"}, "Carro", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Carro Expandido" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Consultas Mescladas", "Carro", {"Marca"}, {"Carro.Marca"}),
    #"Erros Removidos" = Table.RemoveRowsWithErrors(#"Carro Expandido", {"Valor Total do Serviço (REV.)"}),
    #"Linhas Filtradas1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Erros Removidos", each [#"Valor Total do Serviço (REV.)"] < 2000),
    #"Coluna Duplicada1" = Table.DuplicateColumn(#"Linhas Filtradas1", "Modelo", "Modelo - Copiar"),
    #"Dividir Coluna por Delimitador" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Coluna Duplicada1", "Modelo - Copiar", Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({" "}, QuoteStyle.Csv, false), {"Modelo - Copiar.1", "Modelo - Copiar.2"}),
    #"Tipo Alterado2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Dividir Coluna por Delimitador",{{"Modelo - Copiar.1", type text}, {"Modelo - Copiar.2", type text}}),
    #"Colunas Renomeadas" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Tipo Alterado2",{{"Modelo - Copiar.1", "Marca"}}),
    #"Texto em Maiúscula" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Colunas Renomeadas",{{"Marca", Text.Upper, type text}})
in
    #"Texto em Maiúscula"
```

Power bi cannot convert type nvarchar to datetime type/format from sql server.
DataSource.Error: Microsoft SQL: A conversão de um tipo de dados nvarchar em um tipo de dados datetime resultou em um valor fora do intervalo.
Details:

**Edit in response to suggested solution**:

Ok, i've tried this step, but was unsuccessful[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7Gyc.png)

Additionally, I was searching, and it is probably that we'll have to set the data type to Brazilian format, like: `Cast= (Date.ToText([date], "dd/mm/yyyy"))`. Something like that, I think the error is exactly when power bi is trying to take the American date "mm/dd" format from SQL and is unable to convert it to Brazilian format, because it can't even load the query from SQL.

But I've checked in SQL and everything is fine, no issues in SQL side instead, so power bi is failing to convert that date from the SQL database.

Adding steps with Full query and cyclical error during validation

Comment: Where is the error occurring? You have a step, `#"Linhas Filtradas"` which is filtering on a datetime value. You also have a step after that, `#"Tipo Alterado"` where you cast a copy of that column as a date. Which of these is throwing an error? Can you share the schema of the source table (columns and types from the table declaration in SQL)? Can you provide a simpler query sample that has the same error? There are a lot of steps unrelated to your error. Finally, make sure to wrap code in backticks to format it [see this link for editing guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: You are right, thank you for your comment, my issue is being displayed in the very first line, probably in the data conversion nvarchar:

    #"Linhas Filtradas" = Table.SelectRows(serverx, each [DataMovimentacao] > #datetime(2019, 6, 1, 0, 0, 0)),

Sorry to mess the post, first time trying this website.

Comment: No worries, just trying to help you ask questions in a way that will help others answer them. Can you provide samples of the data in the source [DataMovimentacao] column? Are they all formatted as dates, or do you have non-date-looking text there?

Comment: It seems to me that use of the field `[DataMovimentacao]` as though it were a date without having cast it as a date is asking for trouble.  Can you insert a change datatype step prior to #"Linhas Filtradas" and convert `[DataMovimentacao]` to datetime?

Comment: @greggyb I dont know how to paste image here, but no they aren't all formatted as date, just the column [DataMovimentacao] (Data in portuguese is "date"). I have text:

IdFluxo IdFluxoItem                  DataMovimentacao
  5               27                          06/03/2019 11:13:58
  5               27                          22/10/2018 16:15:21
  5              27                          01/11/2018 15:39:49

Just to state, i think is the conversion of american date to portuguese date.

Comment: @RyanB. 

Yes, that is what i want to do, but i dont know which format will accept, i've tried some samples here, which are generated automatically when I type date, like: "datetime.date".
But I don't know which type after or where to insert it in the code.

I think this is the key to solve the problem.

Comment: You can edit your question to include screenshots, or preferably a textual representation that answerers might be able to copy and paste.

Comment: If you need to respond, use a comment, or edit your original post. Don't edit answers to reply to authors.

Comment: Ok, I did it with the original post, that was my fear because it is getting a mess.
Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the error is d/t doing a direct comparison of a VARCHAR field to a datetime value.

Try adding a new step between `dbo_vw_PS` and `#"Linhas Filtradas"` that first casts the field [DataMovimentacao] to a date type:

```
let
    Fonte = Sql.Database("serverx", "xx"),
    dbo_vw_PS = Fonte{[Schema="dbo",Item="dbo_vw_PS"]}[Data],
    CastToDate =
        Table.TransformColumnTypes(
            dbo_vw_PS,
            {{"DataMovimentacao", type date}}),
    #"Linhas Filtradas" =
        Table.SelectRows(
            CastToDate,
            each [DataMovimentacao] > #datetime(2019, 6, 1, 0, 0, 0)),
    ...
```

You're introducing a new step, the variable `CastToDate`, and you are changing `#"Linhas Filtradas"` to reference that variable. The rest of the query would remain the same.

**Edit**:

Okay, first of all, the error you're seeing in the screenshot you shared means you've got an invalid M query. Please post the full query you have made after updates.

Second, the original error indicates that your SQL type is, in fact, VARCHAR, rather than any date type, so we can't use any of the `Date.To...` functions. We aren't working with dates. We're working with text. We're trying to make the text a date.

We can get a datetime value from a text field with `DateTime.FromText(<date string>, <culture string>)`. A specific example is `DateTime.FromText("22/10/2018 16:15:21", "pt-BR") // => #datetime(2018,10,22,16,15,21)`.

My original hope was that just casting as datetime would detect the format, but this seems not to be the case in PQ.

So, we can update our new step as follows. Instead of a type cast we will transform the string explicitly. To avoid M syntax issues, I've put the full text of the updated query below.

The specific transform step:

```
    CastToDate =
        Table.TransformColumns(    // Note we're using Table.TransformColumns instead of Table.TransformColumnTypes
            dbo_vw_PS,
            {{"DataMovimentacao", each DateTime.FromText(_, "pt-BR"), DateTime.Type}}),
```

ANd the full query.

```
let
    Fonte = Sql.Database("serverx", "xx"),
    dbo_vw_PS = Fonte{[Schema="dbo",Item="dbo_vw_PS"]}[Data],
    CastToDate =
        Table.TransformColumns(    // Note we're using Table.TransformColumns instead of Table.TransformColumnTypes
            dbo_vw_PS,
            {{"DataMovimentacao", each DateTime.FromText(_, "pt-BR"), DateTime.Type}}),
    #"Linhas Filtradas" =
        Table.SelectRows(
            CastToDate,
            each [DataMovimentacao] > #datetime(2019, 6, 1, 0, 0, 0)),
    #"Linhas Classificadas" = Table.Sort(#"Linhas Filtradas",{{"DataMovimentacao", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Tipo Alterado" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Linhas Classificadas",{{"Valor Total do Serviço (REV.)", Currency.Type}, {"Valor Total das Peças (REV.)", Currency.Type}}),
    #"Coluna Duplicada" = Table.DuplicateColumn(#"Tipo Alterado", "DataMovimentacao", "DataMovimentacao - Copiar"),
    #"Tipo Alterado1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Coluna Duplicada",{{"DataMovimentacao - Copiar", type date}}),
    #"Consultas Mescladas" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Tipo Alterado1", {"IdCarro"}, Carro, {"Id"}, "Carro", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Carro Expandido" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Consultas Mescladas", "Carro", {"Marca"}, {"Carro.Marca"}),
    #"Erros Removidos" = Table.RemoveRowsWithErrors(#"Carro Expandido", {"Valor Total do Serviço (REV.)"}),
    #"Linhas Filtradas1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Erros Removidos", each [#"Valor Total do Serviço (REV.)"] < 2000),
    #"Coluna Duplicada1" = Table.DuplicateColumn(#"Linhas Filtradas1", "Modelo", "Modelo - Copiar"),
    #"Dividir Coluna por Delimitador" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Coluna Duplicada1", "Modelo - Copiar", Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({" "}, QuoteStyle.Csv, false), {"Modelo - Copiar.1", "Modelo - Copiar.2"}),
    #"Tipo Alterado2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Dividir Coluna por Delimitador",{{"Modelo - Copiar.1", type text}, {"Modelo - Copiar.2", type text}}),
    #"Colunas Renomeadas" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Tipo Alterado2",{{"Modelo - Copiar.1", "Marca"}}),
    #"Texto em Maiúscula" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Colunas Renomeadas",{{"Marca", Text.Upper, type text}})
in
    #"Texto em Maiúscula"
```

Comment: the issue was solved, the problem was indeed inside a SQL account view (the one linked in power bi) whose didnt have the correct datetime in english to portuguese.

In one of the sql accounts the table was loading properly, so we checked and converted to the same datetime and worked (that's why I said in SQL was ok, because indeed it was, but not in the one which was linked with BI).

Lol.. thank you guys, and sorry to waste your time, the whole issue was rooted in SQL.